# Microsoft Word Object Library backwards compatibility

Tags: vb6, ms-office

I have a legacy VB6 application that I need to make a small change to.  The VB project references the `Microsoft Word 9.0 Object Library`.  I only have Office 2016 installed, so I tried to change the reference to `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library`, which is the closest thing I could find in the list of available references (note that the 2016 one is listed as *Office*, not *Word*.  I'm not sure if this is a problem or not).

When I try to compile the application, I get the following error message:

[Can't find project or library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0gnk.png)

Users with Office 2016 installed have been using the application without any compatibility issues, so I should be able to build it without installing Word 2007, right?

What do I need to do to be able to compile the application?

Comment: I downgraded to Office 2010, which seemed to do the trick.  I am now able to reference both `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library` and `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library`.